# What are the component values needed in a Ćuk converter?

Tags: dc-dc-converter

I have been trying to make a Ćuk converter for a long time now. I am using a 555 timer to control the switch. The maximum output voltage that I get is 1.5 V in my design and also in my circuit, though I supply an input of 9 V.

Whenever I measure the input across the battery after connecting, it drops down to 4 V and even less for some reason. Even if the input voltage drops to 4 V I still want least 4 V on the output, if not 9 V.

I have attached the circuit. The inductors are 1 mH and 0.25 mH, and the capacitors are 1000 μF and 1200 μF. I have tried interchanging the positions of these four components as well, but it makes no difference.

[image]

Comment: Don't use 1N400x diodes - they can have really bad reverse recovery times and make efficiency rather bad.

Comment: Also, if you're pulling a 9V battery down to 4V you're seriously overloading it. You haven'n said anything about the current you need.

Comment: @syed what is your specs including output voltage

Answer (score 1):

A boost can be obtained by making the inductor before the MOSFET as large as possible which will store the current (1H or around that is a good value). The second inductor must be near to 0.3mH to avoid much large stop to the current flow while storing it as well in stepping down voltages. With these specific values of inductors and using a 100uF capacitor near the diode and a 1000uF capacitor across the load, I had observed voltage magnitudes as high as 100V with  a 12V input from power supply. To avoid faulty inductors I had used transformers, though pulse transformers (can be found in mobile chargers and CFL lamps/energy savers) were a more better option as they also prevented the 555 and the MOSFET from burning up by keeping the max voltage around 77V